# ルートファイルシステムを復旧させたいのにfsckが上手く使えない

Tags: linux, centos

vagrant + virtualboxを使い、CentOS6.7をゲストOSとして起動させ、それを環境としてシステム開発をしています。(デプロイ先のサーバーと環境を揃えるためです)
ホストOSはubuntu.15.10です。

今日、`vagrant ssh`が失敗するので、virtualbox自身のターミナルからrootユーザーでログインし、`fsck -n` を実行すると

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
...
...
Free blocks count wrong (845378, counted=845408)
Free inodes count wrong (309812, counted=309769)
```

と表示されました。
`/etc/fstab`を確認し、

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=d197cae3-0dd5-4555-9b2f-f9f21c1d9679 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

ルートファイルシステムに異常があるのだとわかりました。

このため、何とかして`fsck`をルートファイルシステムに実行したいのですが、マウントしたままだとファイルシステムを壊してしまうと以前聞いたことがあったので、それなら何とかルートディレクトリからアンマウントしなければと考えました。

そこでシングルユーザーモードで起動しなおし、それから

```
umount /
fsck /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
```

としたところ、

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root clean ...
```

と表示されました。
ファイルシステムに何の問題もないはずがないのですが、とにかくこれ以上何も起きません。
わからないなりに以下のようにもして何か確認できないかとやってみました。

```
# fsck -fv -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
pass 1: checking ...
...
...
pass 5: group summary information

130829 inodes used
...
...
913928 blocks used
  0 bad blocks 
  1 large file
...
...
```

(virtual boxのターミナルで上手く画面をマウスでコピーできないため、要点になりそうなところだけかいつまんでいます。全部の詳細を書けずすみません)

これを見ても、bad blocks が 0 というのは理解ができません。
マルチユーザーモードで起動した時にだけ`fsck`がおかしくなるとでも言うのでしょか？

多分、fsckの使い方を間違えているのか、もっと違うところを
間違っているかだろうと思うのですが、
今日一日ずっと調べていても分かりませんでした。
プログラミングの質問とは違いますが、このままではそのプログラミングができません。
すみませんがどなたかアドバイスをお願いいたします。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: [追記]ちなみに`vagrant ssh`が失敗するのがネットワークなどの問題ではないとなぜ切り分けたのかといいますと、ほとんどは推定の域を出てはいませんが、大体以下のことからゲストOSの問題だと推測しました。１. vagrant sshを実行した後、たまにログイン自体ができたことはありますが、その後全く何のキーを押しても反応しなかったり、最初だけ反応していて、突然ディレクトリの移動ができなくなったりした。2. そもそもゲストOSの起動そのものが異常に遅くなっていた。3.実は以前ubuntuでも似たようなことを１度だけ起こしていたが、そのときは他人に助けてもらってよくはわからないがとにかくなおった。 この３点からゲストOS自身に何かが起きたのだと調べてみて、最初にfsckをしたところ、上記質問の現象に遭遇した次第です。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

シングルユーザモードで `/` を読み取り専用で再マウントして `fsck` を実行すれば良いと思います。

```
# mount -o ro,remount /
# fsck -t ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
# reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

「bad blocks」はハードディスクでいうところの不良セクターのことではないでしょうか。
fsck でエラーとなっているのは「bad blocks」があるからではなく、フリーブロック数とフリー i-node 数の実際の値がファイルシステム側(メタデータに記録されている)よりも少ないということだと思います。
ファイルシステムを縮小する前に LVM や仮想ディスクを縮小したりしていませんでしょうか。

修復方法については take88 さんの回答のとおりです。

Comment: はい、後で分かったことなのですが、おっしゃるとおりでして、基本的にマウントされているデバイスにfsckをかけたときと、マウントから外れたときのfsckの動作が異なるということを理解していませんでした。今回のことは驚きましたが勉強になりました。